# (can't) Get part of an element's style in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm very new to javascript (started messing with it today).

I'm trying to change the height of an element (a div) called 'bar'.
The bar will be part of a chart.

I have no problem hooking up a button to a function which changes the height of the bar. All is working fine, except the bar is growing in the downward direction instead of upward like i wanted.

My solution is to increase the 'height' property, and then decrease the 'top' property
by the height increase amount.

So I want to do something like:

```
bar.style.height = newHeight;
bar.style.top = bar.style.top - newHeight;
```

And that should increase the height upward.
The problem is that I don't know how to get the current value of bar.style.top

In firebug, if I look at the styles in the html tab, the bar has a top of

```
top: 122px;
```

but in the watch list for bar, all i see is the value "" (empty string) for
bar.style.top. I guess my question is - why don't these values match, and how can i get to the value i want?

And one other thing while I'm asking about this stuff:

I have some CSS for webkit that looks like:

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

for example. I notice in the watch list for bar, there is no bar.style.-webkit-animation-timeing-function. How do I get at and change values like that?

I normally use asp.net, I was hoping there was something similar to

```
bar.Style["property"] = "value";
```

Have I missed something here?

Comment: Have you set the `position` property at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Please use `document.getElementById('bar')` instead of just `bar`, because `bar` could mean a lot of different things.
2. The `style` property allows you to override any style but only gives you style set by a `<div style="...">` attribute. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html on how to get the current style.

Comment: 1. In code, I am doing that. Just wanted to save space. bar is an element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bar.style.WebkitAnimationTimingFunction` to access the CSS property via JavaScript.

http://www.codestyle.org/javascript/dom/css/CSS3ExtensionStyles.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going for a bar chart, I would suggest styling a bit differently using "bottom" instead of "top". Then, you just have to change the height. Something like the following:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 20px; height: 40px; background-color: red;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 40px; width: 20px; height: 60px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 70px; width: 20px; height: 80px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```